# Column position influences boolean recognition in pandas.read_csv()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I am having tabulator separated values in files that look like this (note: the only difference is the order of columns):

`first_col.tsv`:

```
name    bool_col    float_col
ist_true    true    1
also_true   1   2
is_false    false   3
also_false  0   4
is_empty        5
```

`last_col.tsv`:

```
name    float_col   bool_col
ist_true    1   true
also_true   2   1
is_false    3   false
also_false  4   0
is_empty    5
```

If I now read both files with the following commands:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(
    <filename>,
    sep="\t|,|;",
    true_values=["1","True","true","yes"],
    false_values=["0","False","false","no"]
).fillna({"bool_col": False}).set_index('name')
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

I'm getting different results for both files:

`first_col.tsv`:

```
            bool_col  float_col
name                           
ist_true        True          1
also_true       True          2
is_false       False          3
also_false     False          4
is_empty       False          5

bool_col      bool
float_col    int64
dtype: object
```

`last_col.tsv`:

```
            float_col bool_col
name                          
ist_true            1     true
also_true           2        1
is_false            3    false
also_false          4        0
is_empty            5    False

float_col     int64
bool_col     object
dtype: object
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and what I can do to always get the expected result -> a full boolean column?

I have tried the same with comma separated files: There the behavior is as expected, both cases have a full boolean column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because there is a difference between your two files: the column order. In the first TSV file, the empty cell is defined to `NaN` rather than in the second one, the empty cell is set to `None` which is different. You can append `None` to the list of `false_values`

```
params = {'sep': "\t|,|;", 'engine': 'python',
          'true_values': ["1","True","true","yes"],
          'false_values': ["0","False","false","no"]}

>>> pd.read_csv('first_col.tsv', **params)
         name bool_col  float_col
0    ist_true     True          1
1   also_true     True          2
2    is_false    False          3
3  also_false    False          4
4    is_empty      NaN          5

>>> pd.read_csv('last_col.tsv', **params)
         name  float_col bool_col
0    ist_true          1     true
1   also_true          2        1
2    is_false          3    false
3  also_false          4        0
4    is_empty          5     None  # <- None and not NaN
```

Now modify the `false_values`:

```
params = {'sep': "\t|,|;", 'engine': 'python',
          'true_values': ["1","True","true","yes"],
          'false_values': ["0","False","false","no",None]}  # <- HERE

>>> pd.read_csv('last_col.tsv', **params)
         name  float_col  bool_col
0    ist_true          1      True
1   also_true          2      True
2    is_false          3     False
3  also_false          4     False
4    is_empty          5     False
```

You can also append `NaN` to the list of `false_values`:

```
params = {'sep': "\t|,|;", 'engine': 'python',
          'true_values': ["1","True","true","yes"],
          'false_values': ["0","False","false","no",None,np.nan]}  # <- HERE

>>> pd.read_csv('first_col.tsv', **params)
         name  bool_col  float_col
0    ist_true      True          1
1   also_true      True          2
2    is_false     False          3
3  also_false     False          4
4    is_empty     False          5
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a really good explanation and solution. It is also robust against `bool_col` being missing entirely, a case I didn't mention in my original question to avoid over complicating things, but that is relevant for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not only due to `read_csv`, but to the fact that booleans and numbers cannot share a common type other than `object`:

```
pd.Series([1, True]).dtype
# dtype('O')
```

You need to explicitly map values and convert to boolean after import`

```
mapper = {"1": 1, "True": 1, "true": 1, "yes": 1, "0": 0, "False": 0, "false": 0, "no": 0, "": 0}

df = pd.read_csv(
    filename,
    sep="\t|,|;",
    engine='python',
).replace({"bool_col": mapper}).astype({'bool_col': bool}).set_index('name')

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    filename,
    sep="\t|,|;",
    engine='python',
).assign(bool_col=lambda d: d['bool_col'].isin(true_values))
```

Comment: With your suggestion, all rows that have a value, regardless what it's content is, become true

Comment: I provided a workaround

Comment: Thank you @mozway. After adding the `.fillna({"bool_col": False)` before the `replace`-part, also the the row with the missing values is correctly read as `False`.

Comment: If you edit your answer accordingly, I will gladly accept it as the answer. Is there any explanation why it works as expected with comma separated file?